# Что такое init-statement и где оно используется?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Что такое `init-statement`? Недавно прочитал в интернете про [if с инициализатором](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if). По данным этого же сайта прочитал, что у цикла for так, же на первом месте в скобках стоит `init-statement`. Я понимаю, что это как обычное объявление, но почему-то для этого существует отдельный термин. Я очень бы хотел разобраться в терминологии и узнать где еще используется `init-statement`, заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Это не обязательно объявление. Например `for (i = 42; /*...*/; /*...*/)` разрешено, хотя `i = 42` - это выражение, а не объявление.

`init-statement` - это термин грамматики, означающий выражение (после которого стоит `;`) **или** объявление.

Убедимся в этом. Открываем [грамматику](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.pre#nt:init-statement) и видим:

```
init-statement:
    expression-statement
    simple-declaration
```

Это значит, что `init-statement` - это или `expression-statement`, или `simple-declaration`.

```
expression-statement:
    expressionopt ;
```

[`expression-statement`](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.expr#nt:expression-statement) - это выражение (`expression`), справа от которого стоит точка с запятой. `opt` (= "optional" = "опционально") значит, что выражения может и не быть, т.е. сама по себе `;` - это тоже `expression-statement`.

`simple-declaration` - это обычное объявление 1 или нескольких переменных. Его описание в грамматике сложное, поэтому показывать не буду. Интересно, что определить структуру здесь тоже можно: `for (struct A { /*...*/ }; /*...*/; /*...*/)`, ведь это считается объявлением (объявляющим 0 переменных)...

Comment: Получается init-statement можно считать за обычный statement, как и следующие 2 "параметра" в скобках (если они есть) у цикла for?

Comment: @n1kzzz Нет, почему. Есть [много видов statement-ов](http://eel.is/c++draft/gram.stmt) кроме выражений и объявлений переменных. И все эти другие виды не могут быть первым параметром `for`. Например `if (...) {...}` это один большой statement (включающий и условие, и тело if-а), а его тело вместе с фигурными скобками - это тоже statement. Вы же не можете написать `for (if (...) {...} ...; ...)`. Также statement-ами являются `return ...;`, `break;`, `continue;`, и т. п.

Comment: @n1kzzz [Третий параметр](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.iter.general#nt:iteration-statement) не может быть statement-ом, ведь в нем нет `;`. Это просто выражение. Второй параметр в грамматике называется [`condition`](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.pre#nt:condition), и является либо выражением, либо объявлением ровно одной переменной - еще более строгое ограничение, чем для первого параметра.

Comment: Извините, что задаю вопрос через столь долгое время просто, я опять вернулся к этой теме. Если второй параметр является обычным выражением (не statement), то почему тогда после него ставится точка с запятой?

Comment: @n1kzzz Вторая точка с запятой не является частью выражения, она прибита гвоздями к самому for-у (см. [тут](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.iter.general#nt:iteration-statement)).

Comment: Извините пожалуйста за столь тупой вопрос, а если на месте condition стоит объявление а не выражение? Разве после объявления не должна стоять точка с запятой ( я не про ту, что прописана в синтаксисе цикла for, а про пунктуатор, который обычно ставится например после statement'ов)

Comment: @n1kzzz Вопрос интересный. Оказывается, у объявления в условии своя [особая грамматика](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.pre#nt:condition) без `;`, отличающаяся от грамматики обычных объявлений.

Comment: Если что, что я не из головы вспоминаю все эти тонкости грамматики. Я просто смотрю в стандарт.